# Git checkout commit, do stuff, and go back to master

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I have a build system that takes a git repository, goes back to a specific commit, and then uploads those files some where. Then is goes back to master.

I'm unsure that I'm using the right Git commands, as Git will give me this message whenever I perform a `git checkout SHA`:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

The only thing I want to do is to reset my working directory to a specific commit, upload those files, and go back to HEAD/master. I might make a few changes to files when I go to the specific commit SHA (convert XML to JSON or something), but I just want to loose all of those changes when I go back to master. Right now this is my code

```
git checkout SHA

# do a bunch of conversion and uploading

git checkout master
```

Is that the preferred way of doing what I want? Will I always be able to do pulls from the origin without getting any file conflicts (I don't want to keep whatever I'm doing between the checkouts)?

I'm asking because I'm seeing "your master and origin/master diverged" some times, although I'm not sure it's caused by this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: say `git config advice.detachedhead false` to silence that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly OK to do this. When HEAD isn't corresponding to a branch name it will be shown as a detached HEAD. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `git show SHA1:relative/path` to take a snapshot of file at specific point.

Comment: This will only list the files and not change my working directory, right?

Comment: Yes, it will just show specific version of file for given SHA.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned pulling changes from the origin. In your case you may also use `git reset --hard SHA1` to go back to a specific commit and then `git pull` the missing changes from `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

For what you describe, you can just do something like:

git archive -o /some/where/archive.tar.gz --prefix=<something> <commit> <file list>

Look at the manual for git archive for the gory details. You can create zip files, tar files (compressed or not), opionally place a prefix "above" the packed files, all taken from the referenced commit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to publish API, test and code coverage reports back up to my github page (gh-pages branch) after a successful Bamboo build. Its an Ant target that does the kind of thing you describe. (Lots of good answers here, but posting in case it helps).

```
<target name="--publish.site">
    <echo file="${temp.dir}/publish-site.sh">
        #!/bin/sh
        cd ${basedir}
        cp -fr ${basedir}/schema ${reports.dir}
        git remote set-url origin git@github.com:jasperblues/my-project.git
        git fetch origin gh-pages:gh-pages
        git checkout gh-pages
        git pull
        rm -fr ./coverage
        cp -fr ${reports.dir}/coverage/ ./coverage
        git add ./coverage
        rm -fr ./api
        cp -fr ${reports.dir}/api ./api
        git add api
        cp -fr ${reports.dir}/schema ./schema
        git add schema
        git commit -a -m "publish reports to gh-pages"
        git push -u origin gh-pages
        git checkout master
    </echo>
    <chmod perm="+x" file="${temp.dir}/publish-site.sh"/>
    <exec executable="${temp.dir}/publish-site.sh" failonerror="true" failifexecutionfails="true">
        <env key="PATH" value="${tools.paths}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```